# content_tag :tr block in simple English

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a beginner to Rails and I saw this block of code somewhere and was wondering what the code exactly does in relation to the HEADER variable that is defined as an array of the seven days.

```
def header
  content_tag :tr do
    HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is able to create HTML like this :

```
<tr>
  <th> first day </th>
  <th> second day </th>
  .....................
  <th> Seventh day </th>
</tr>
```

**Explanation :**

The map method takes an enumerable object and a block, and runs the block for each element, outputting each returned value from the block.

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |n| n * n } #=> [1, 4, 9]
```

The Join method used to convert the output array to a string and html_safe is used to proper rendering of HTML on web page.